# Executing of Python script

Tags: python

I found Python script for my task, but I don't know how I can execute this script on server with parameter (on my local machine I do it with command line). If this script is by address `www.aaa.com/abc.py`, then how can I execute it with parameters by browser or else?

Comment: what web server is running on the server ?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to run the Python script from a CGI script.

First, create a CGI script, `abc.sh` like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "HTTP 200 OK"
echo "Content-type: text/plain"
echo ""
./abc.py 2>&1
```

Make sure to `chmod +x abc.sh`, and stick both `abc.sh` and `abc.py` in your `cgi-bin` directory.

Then you should be able to visit `example.com/cgi-bin/abc.sh`, which will run the Python script.

Comment: Hacktastic - I love it :-)

One addition I'd suggest to allow arguments to be passed:

Change `./abc.py 2>&1` to `./abc.py \`echo $QUERY_STRING | sed 's/%20/ /g'\` 2>&1`

Now you can pass parameters in the URL from your browser, just like you can on the command line:

example.com/cgi-bin/abc.sh arg1 arg2 arg_etc

;-P

Comment: The only issue with that is that you could accidentally open yourself up to exploits… I'd rather use `./abc.py "$QUERY_STRING"`, then let the python script handle it.